# Highlight uneven/even months with conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The numbers in line *A1 to M1* are months. *01 means Jan, 02 means Feb* and so on.
I tried to set this new rule `=ISEVEN(MONTH(A1:M1))` for a conditional formatting. I want to mark all the months which are *uneven* and *even*. Means for example(*Jan green* *Feb white* *March green* *April* *white* and so on). But when I execute my formula I can't see a result.

[image: table for conditional formatting]

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the first row is formatted as month you can use this: =ISEVEN(A1) in the formatting for all the even months.

For the odd values use the: =ISODD(A1).

[image]

Comment: exactly, that's it! But it 01 is formatted as month, is it okey?

Comment: Yes, in the example above I formatted it as month before I applied the conditional formatting.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If `A1` always is *Jan* then this would be enough:

Select the range `A1:M1` then in conditional formatting you can put `=ISODD(A1)` .A1 indicates the first cell in your selected range, you can change it as you need, into the Format values where this formula is true.

**EDIT**
Tried to format as `TEXT`as I guess you have and still Works as formula but not in CF

Comment: `=MOD(MONTH($A1),2)` can I use something like that? @krib

Comment: @flowers1234 maybe more like `=MOD(A1,2)=1` i Guess. not testet, if you want ODD numbers highlighted. You can just change the entire background then apply CF.

Comment: when I execute yours I get all  the months marked :D

Comment: I cant fix it. The problem is that the 01 02 are formatted as MONTH

Comment: Is that With just the month playing in the back or is it the full date? If its the full date the day is whats being checked as ODD

Comment: No. It is only the month

Comment: Even though the first row is formatted as month you can use this: ```=ISEVEN(A1)``` in the formatting for all the even months.

Comment: cant create that error myself. Not sure whats the issue @flowers1234

Comment: For the odd values use the: ```=ISODD(A1)```